# How to get rid of a persistent iOS app?

Tags: ios

Last year in Spain, I got a free app to manage my cell phone service.  I no longer have an iPhone, and the app is useless unless I have that account in that country.

So I deleted the app from my iPad, but it keeps reappearing as an available update.  I keep deleting it to save update bandwidth, but it is there repeatedly.

I know the workaround is to skip its update, but due to circumstances, I have to go some time between updates, and it is quite convenient to "update all" instead of tapping one or two dozen choices.

So how do I completely get rid of this thing?

Comment: In contrast, here I am in Spain again, and the App Store refuses to give me the app for my current data plan because I'm not Spanish.  While Google won't sell me their world-wide service because I am not in USA.

Comment: Are you sure you have removed the app from the iPad? My experience is that if the app is not on the device, the update does not happen. Perhaps you can search for the app on the iPad and find it burried in some folder or screen that you have missed.

Comment: That was my experience prior to this one.  But I KNOW I have deleted this thing more than once.  Its name is Tuenti if anyone cares.

Comment: Maybe the update was pending when it was deleted or something similar causing the various lists of what is installed or needs to be undated to get out of wack. Perhaps reinstalling it, updating it, and when there are no updates pending, then deleting it, might be effective.

Comment: Ah, that may be the deal.  I saw it listed for update, and went to delete it first.  So maybe that's why it kept coming back.  If it comes back again, I'll give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

If the update was pending when it was deleted or something similar, then the various lists of what is installed or needs to be undated may have gotten out of wack.

Perhaps reinstalling it, updating it, and when there are no updates pending, then deleting it, might be effective.

Comment: No longer a problem.  Apparently replacing a stolen iPad is one way of clearing such a problem.  :-)

Comment: Yeah, i imaging replacing a iPad run over by a truck would be equally effective :-)